# Android Gallery View

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am looking for any open source Gallery view Plugin for Android. I have tried out the in built gallery view at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Just want to explore any other gallery that has been implemented out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can look at [Android Coverflow Widget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html) but it still extends gallery view

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a slideshow/photoframe app which has been open-sourced and made available on [github](https://github.com/elsewhat/com.elsewhat.android.slideshow) . Feel free to fork it.

This project is used in the Photo Voyages of Trey Ratcliff market app [Market link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.stuckincustoms.slideshow.premium)